# codegen CLI Multiple file with option -DsupportingFiles=

Tags: swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am trying to generate a server with openapi-generator, I want to select the supporting files I create. I understand there is the option `-DsupportingFiles=StringUtil.java`. This example come from this [page](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization.html).

My question is quite simple how can I choose the list of files to generate. I succeed to generate one file at a time. In the docs they talk about a CSV format, I have tried all those options, but nothing seems to work.

```
-DsupportingFiles=encoder.py,util.py
-DsupportingFiles="encoder.py","util.py"
-DsupportingFiles=encoder.py;util.py
```

Anyone know if this is possible or even if it is the right way to do this ?

Comment: there's an open ticket on github: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/811. In the description they say there's the problem for both -Dmodels and -DsupportingFiles

Comment: Actually it seems to be working if you put -DsupportingFiles right after the java command: `java -DsupportingFiles=A.java,B.java -jar openapi-client.jar generate -i ..`